# Candlesticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cryptocurrency, mpf

I'm trying to make a cryptoscanner but I'm struggling a bit. The code right now can loop through the different coins in symbols.csv and print plots for all of them. The plots include close price, SMA and bollinger bands. Now I really want the close price to be candlesticks and not a line. I've found that there are other plots like mpf to make candlesticks. The problem is that I don't know how to make the bollinger bands work with the mpf plots and I don't know how to make the candlesticks work with matplotlib. Can someone help me making candlesticks in matplotlib orrr make the bollingerbands in the mpf plots.

Thanks in advance!

[The graph looks like this right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zyTs.png)

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib



with open('symbols.csv') as f:
    symbols = f.read().splitlines()
    for symbol in symbols:
        df = yf.download(symbol, start='2020-01-01')
        # df = yf.download(symbol, period = '22h', interval = '15m')
        print(df)



# df = yf.download('ADA-USD', start='2021-01-01')

        df['SMA'] = df.Close.rolling(window=20).mean()
        df['stddev'] = df.Close.rolling(window=20).std()
        df['Upper'] = df.SMA + 2* df.stddev
        df['Lower'] = df.SMA - 2* df.stddev
        df['Buy_Signal'] = np.where(df.Lower > df.Close, True, False)
        df['Sell_Signal'] = np.where(df.Upper < df.Close, True, False)

        buys = []
        sells = []
        open_pos = False

        for i in range(len(df)):
            if df.Lower[i] > df.Close[i]:
                if open_pos == False:
                    buys.append(i)
                    open_pos = True
            elif df.Upper[i] < df.Close[i]:
                if open_pos:
                    sells.append(i)
                    open_pos = False



        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

        plt.scatter(df.iloc[buys].index, df.iloc[buys].Close, marker = '^', color ='g')
        plt.scatter(df.iloc[sells].index, df.iloc[sells].Close, marker = '^', color ='r')


        plt.plot(df[['Close', 'SMA', 'Upper', 'Lower']])
        plt.fill_between(df.index, df.Upper, df.Lower, color='grey', alpha=0.3)
        plt.legend(['Close', 'SMA', 'Upper', 'Lower'])
        plt.show()

        merged = pd.concat([df.iloc[buys].Close, df.iloc[sells].Close], axis=1)
        merged.columns = ['Buys', 'Sells']
        print(merged)
        totalprofit = merged.shift(-1).Sells - merged.Buys
        print(totalprofit)
        relprofits = (merged.shift(-1).Sells - merged.Buys) / merged.Buys
        print(relprofits.mean())
```

Comment: You should probably use https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links in the comments provide a wealth of [examples](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb). Since you want to graph candlesticks, Bollinger Bands, and SMAs in mpf, I have modified the additional plot examples from the previous examples to suit your needs. The graphs were created from data obtained in stocks instead of currencies.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2020-01-01")

df['SMA'] = df.Close.rolling(window=20).mean()
df['stddev'] = df.Close.rolling(window=20).std()
df['Upper'] = df.SMA + 2* df.stddev
df['Lower'] = df.SMA - 2* df.stddev
df['Buy_Signal'] = np.where(df.Lower > df.Close, True, False)
df['Sell_Signal'] = np.where(df.Upper < df.Close, True, False)

tcdf = df[['Lower','Upper','SMA']]
apd = mpf.make_addplot(tcdf)
mpf.plot(df, figratio=(8,4), type='candle', addplot=apd, volume=False, style='yahoo')
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the [case study](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/tree/master/examples) here. If my answer was helpful to you, please click the check mark to accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I was busy with my study so wasn't paying attention here.